# Storing 2 columns into a List

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, list, c#-4.0, multidimensional-array

How can I store data from 2 columns (from a database) in a List

```
List<string> _items = new List<string>();
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Dictionary? List<Tuple<string,string>>?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can also make array of list

```
List<string> [] list= new List<String> [];
list[0]=new List<string>();
list[1]=new List<string>();

list[0].add("hello");
list[1].add("world");
```

Comment: I don't see why this was the answer, then the question was about a List, not an Array of a List.

Answer (score 58):

You create a class that will represent a row with 2 columns:

```
public class Foo
{
    // obviously you find meaningful names of the 2 properties

    public string Column1 { get; set; } 
    public string Column2 { get; set; }
}
```

and then you store in a `List<Foo>`:

```
List<Foo> _items = new List<Foo>();
_items.Add(new Foo { Column1 = "bar", Column2 = "baz" });
```

Comment: how would I get the data from my new class?

Comment: @CocoaDev, this will greatly depend on how is your data stored in the database, what database access technology are you using, if you are using an ORM tool or not, ... There are like gazillions of possibilities here. If have no clue where to start, ADO.NET is the de-facto database access technology in .NET that every developer doing relational database programming should start with when learning relational data access.

Comment: I am getting the data from an Excel spreadsheet then storing it into a List (the example you showed me). So basically at this point. My data is being held in a variable called _items3

Comment: @CocoaDev, OK, so what is your question? How are you retrieving the data from this Excel spreadsheet or is it what you are asking?

Comment: My existing code (will need to be updated for 2nd column) was Listbox1.DataSource = _items3. This is when items3 was a List<string>. Now items3 is a List<Foo>. So how would I get the data from the items3 to appear as Text in the Listbox1.DataSource

Comment: @CocoaDev, you could set the `DataTextField` and the `DataValueField` properties of the ListBox (assuming you are talking about an ASP.NET ListBox control) to the corresponding property names. For example: `ListBox1.DataTextField = "Column1";`. If you are doing WinForm development the two properties that you are looking for are called `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember`.

Comment: I dont think it works like that. ListBox1 is inside "public partial class Form1 : Form". How is ListBox1.DisplayMember = items3.Column1?

Comment: I get this error Warning 1 The class Form1 can be designed, but is not the first class in the file.  Visual Studio requires that designers use the first class in the file.  Move the class code so that it is the first class in the file and try loading the designer again.  0 0

Comment: @CocoaDev - this is old but I think you need to do a little more research unto what Darin is telling you.

Answer (score 29):

Use a tuple struct like [KeyValuePair](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42.aspx)

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> _items = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
_items.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(foo, bar));
```

Answer (score 7):

I would use a class

```
 List<MyDataClass> _items = new List<MyDataClass>();

 public class MyDataClass
 {
     public string Value1 { get; set; }
     public string Value2 { get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: Can you show me how you would get/set the data using your class. SO far it looks like a great start.

Answer (score 3):

You can either create a new class to hold the data, Or you could use the built in `Tuple<>` class. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx

Also if one of the columns contains a unique ID of some sort, you could also consider using a `Dictionary<>`.

Answer (score 0):

It's about how to retrieve the data from the new two columns list

```
List<ListTwoColumns> JobIDAndJobName = new List<ListTwoColumns>();
    for (int index = 0; index < JobIDAndJobName.Count;index++)
            {
                ListTwoColumns List = JobIDAndJobName[index];
                if (List.Text == this.cbJob.Text)
                {
                    JobID = List.ID;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is pretty old and by now you probably got your answer and have figured out what you need but I wanted to add something that might help someone in the future.

The best current answer is frankly from @csharptest.net but it has a serious performance drawback and so here is my approach a la his answer based on a suggestion to use `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`

```
private Dictionary<string, string> _items = new Dictionary<string, string>();  

// if you need to check to see if it exists already or not
private void AddToList(string one, string two)  
{  
    if (!_items.ContainsKey(one))  
        _items.Add(one, two);  
}

// you can simplify the add further
private void AddToList(string one, string two)  
{  
    _items[one] = two;  

    // note if you try to add and it exists, it will throw exception,
    // so alternatively you can wrap it in try/catch - dealer's choice
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could do this:

```
List<IList<string>> cols = new List<IList<string>>();
```

You can set how many columns you want.

```
cols.Add(new List<string> { "", "", "","more","more","more","more","..." });
```